# prove that there is a function $g:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $\forall {x,y}\in \mathbb R^2\space ;\space f(x,y)=g(x+cy)$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function.
 assume that there is $c\in \mathbb R$ such that for every $(x_0,y_0)\in \mathbb{ R}^2$ ; $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)=c\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)$$

Prove that there is a function $g:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $$\forall {x,y}\in \mathbb R^2\space ;\space f(x,y)=g(x+cy)$$

I am pretty sure that you have to show that if $x_1+c\cdot y_1=x_2+c\cdot y_2$ then $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)$ and define for example  $g(x)=f(x,0)$ yet I don't know how to do that or how the partial derivatives connect to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$ \frac{\partial }{\partial t} f(x-ct, y+t)=0$$

So $f$ is constant on a line $x=-cy+s$. Constant $s$ determine
 value of $f$. Hence $$f(x,y)=g(s)=g(x+cy)$$